# How tell if spokes too tight without tensionometer

Tags: wheels, rims, spokes, wheel-truing

Is there a way to tell if a spoke or spokes are too tight, if you don't have access to a tensionometer?

I had to tighten several, and obviously I don't want them too tight, otherwise you risk broken spokes and damaged nipples/rims/maybe hubs.

Comment: "Twang" them, and compare to the "twang" of other spokes.

Comment: People did build wheels before tensiometers, though its not preferable these days.

Comment: Good tips and perspective, thanks.  My situation is I suspected a loose wheel was causing the brakes to rub (front wheel) while turning right, so I checked it out and most spokes seemed loose, and several seemed very loose.  (I'd checked and trued the back before, but not the front.)  I tightened all at least some and several a lot.  This makes me think I can't use other spokes as a reference, but I guess I could compare with the other wheel, which didn't get adjusted so radically.  Still, since I don't have experience, I'd like an absolute reference, which may be the bike shop this time.

Comment: Did you use any form of spoke prep or thread prep liquid?  Some wheels just want to undo their nipples over time, which often means there was a bit much play.

Comment: @criggie Not so far, this is the first time I've touched the spokes in front.  Thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roger Musson's book "[Professional Guide to Wheel Building](http://www.wheelpro.co.uk/wheelbuilding/book.php)" simply states that: "*The best place to start when judging the correct tension is to examine a similar wheel you know to be good and reliable and compare the spoke tension to the one being built.*"

Musson does not use the sound of the spokes to determine their tension, only to find differences in tension between them.

Roger Musson's website does also have a good discussion about tensionmeters and their necessity when building wheels. http://www.wheelpro.co.uk/support/tensiometers/

Comment: Sound is a surprisingly good way to find odd spokes.  I've had a wheel that made sounds like  tang-tang-tang_THONK_ting-THONK_tang-tang-tang where the ting spoke was way high tension.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you need a similar wheel. I don't have any friends with a similar wheelset to either of my bikes.